# TYPO3 find tt_content from pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I'm using TYPO3 10.4.14

I believe, that I understood the relationship of `pages` and `tt_content`. But I have not figured out, how to get the `tt_content` elements and the order from the table `pages`.

From `tt_content` it is easy to get the page, but not from `pages` to `tt_content`.

What I finally want to do, is to mark a page (additional column), for display the beginning of the page in an overview.

For that I need the content elements of a page!

**Edit:**
I want to do t with database query.

One possible way would to use the `uid` of `pages` and go to the `tt_content` and search there for the `pid`. But this is a long winded way.

How is TYPO3 it doing, when display the pages?

Comment: Can you specify how you want to get all content elements from a page? Database query? TypoScript?

Comment: tt_content has uid and pid, pid is page id? (in database)

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple ways to render any output (typical HTML):

1. typoscript
2. PHP
3. FLUID

(in the end all is PHP, but regarding what you are programming or configuring)

If you want to render some regular content of the current page you will use the defined typoscript `styles.content.get` (with modifications), which is a TypoScript [`CONTENT` object](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html). This will do a query to get those tt_content records which belong to the current page in the default (or other) column. This results in a query like `SELECT * FROM tt_content WHERE pid = current_page_uid AND column = 0` (and some additional conditions regarding visibility (hidden, starttime, endtime, workspace, ...)
This could be assigned to a FLUID variable or requested by a viewhelper ([`f:cObject`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html)).

If you want to get content from another than the current page you need to do a similar request and use another page uid. Either you build your own `CONTENT` object and use it like the default content. Or you build an own viewhelper in PHP which you can use in FLUID. You can modify the query by reducing the number of records you consider, you also can modify the rendering regarding which fields will be shown in what HTML markup.
Depending on the package you use it may contain already specialized viewhelper which gets you the content of other pages and/or other columns.

---

I think you want to build teasers for other pages with the content of that pages.
Consider to use a special field in the pages record which contains a clean summary for the page content. Not each page has relevant or recognizable information in the first paragraph.
It's the same as for search engines: if you provide search engines with a summary, that will be shown at the search results and the searcher can better decide if this page is relevant for him.

Comment: Bernd you are right, I want to build teasers and I want to write my own extension for it. For that I want to add a column to `pages `. This should be the marker to use it in the teaser. I also think about to use a own extension for these pages, so that I can mark the relevant parts. But my main problem is still, how I get the `tt_content` from the `pages`! From the `uid` of `pages` , which is the `pid` in `tt_content`. Is there a direct way or have I always search the whole `tt_content` for `pid`s which meet the `page`?

Comment: as said: try to use the SEO fields. that will give better summaries (and those fields should be field anyway for search engines). then you do not need to do your own queries. if you want to accesss `tt_content`records you need to do queries (`WHERE pid = pagenumber`) but be assured: it will be quick. alas there is no direct access (reference) in the database from `pages` to any records assigned to that page (`tt_content` or others).